# Django pass url context via function

Tags: django, django-views

I have a urlpattern in the urls.py file defined as

```
path('profile/<str:uname>/', views.myview, name='UserProfile'),
```

I need to do the following at the return of my function in my views.py file,

```
def myview(request):
context = {}
if request.user.is_superuser:
    if request.POST:
        form = MyForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            uname = form.cleaned_data.get('uname')
            return render(request, 'UserProfile')
        else:
            pass
    else:
        pass
elif not request.user.is_superuser:
    pass
```

How do I pass the **'uname'** parameter in this **return** correctly?

P.S. I don't know if this is even possible.

**EDIT:** I've added the complete view.

Comment: Please add the rest of your view

Comment: You want to return a redirect with a parameter instead of using `render` to render a template?

Comment: I've tried return redirect('UserProfile', uname = str(uname)), but it gives me Exception Value: UserProfile() got an unexpected keyword argument 'uname'. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Sounds like your view function `UserProfile` needs to accept a keyword argument `uname` that gets passed from the URL - `def UserProfile(request, uname=None):`

Comment: Thanks @IainShelvington This worked, I had to return the redirect instead of render as in my comment above and simply add the uname keyword argument to my UserProfile function. Thank you once again, much appreciated.